# Truncation in python

Tags: python

How can we truncate (not round) the cube root of a given number after the 10th decimal place in python?

For Example:

If number is **8** the required output is **2.0000000000** and for **33076161** it is **321.0000000000**

Comment: I think you should read www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf. There's no guarantee that you can truncate a floating-point number to any number of decimals, it might be incapable of storing the truncated result.

Comment: @unwind: Yes. Truncation should be done at display time only. It's a presentation concern.

Comment: It is interesting that you chose 33076161 as your candidate. Floating point error results in 320.9999 as a result. So you don't want rounding, but you also don't have room for floating point error in your thinking?

Comment: It seems that your question is inspired by some kind of code-golf competition. Why not link to the question.  It seems disingenuous to have StackOverflow write your solutions to challenges that were intended to make you think for yourself. :-)

Comment: @Tretwick: The problem is that the floating point representation of `1/3` is slightly less than the true value of `1/3`.  The true value of 33076161 raised to the power of this rounded exponent actually *is* closer to 320.99999999999989 than to 321, so truncation won't help, regardless what your floating point precisiion is.

Comment: Is there another clever way to find a cube-root in python with logs?

Comment: @Warren: You could use `exp(log(i)/3)`, but this might also be off.

Comment: That works.  Good find! At least in the case above, it outputs 321.0. That just might be a fortunate result of log precision truncation, it might hit floating point limits differently for other cases. :-)

Comment: 321-cubed is one of the cases where all the bits fall apart in a nice way.  310-cubed is one of the cases where it doesn't matter, you get the same .99999.. either way.

Answer (score 2):

Scale - truncate - unscale:

```
n = 10.0
cube_root = 1e-10 * int(1e10 * n**(1.0/3.0))
```

Comment: However, due to floating point precision issues there is no reason to assume that such a truncation will actually result in something that can be accurately processed to exactly 10 decimals of precision. Better to just KEEP all your precision, and handle the truncation only when you print (format strings).

Comment: @Warren P:I am a very new-bie in python could you please explain the format string part (with one example)

Comment: @Warren: string formatting will round, not truncate.  I believe the code above is about the best you can get within the limitations of floating point numbers.  As long as `n` is not too big, there is a reason to assume this will yield something useful.

Comment: Your answer encourages the OP to believe that floating point numbers support accurate truncation as an operation, which they do not.  Show me one incorrect result in my code. I can show you many inaccurate cases with yours.  The OP is laboring under an illusion about floating point accuracy, it seems most helpful to disillusion them.  Your answer is correct within the limits of floating point math, which are considerable.

Comment: @Warren: If someone asked how to divide the floating point numbers stored in `a` and `b`, and I answered `a / b`, would you comment that my answer would make the OP believe floating point numbers support division as an accurate operation?  Of course floating point have limited precision, for any operation whatsoever.

Comment: I see your point.  I guess, I think that it is always valuable to point out to the new guys that there are such limitations. Thanks for reminding me about rounding having "multi-digit-column" side effects!

Comment: @Warren: Granted, that's always valuable.

Comment: Sometimes, I think the OP on SO is a troll.   This is a code golf question, or an interview question.

Answer (score 2):

You should only do such truncations (unless you have a serious reason otherwise) while printing out results. There is no exact binary representation in floating point format, for a whole host of everyday decimal values:

```
print 33076161**(1.0/3.0)
```

A calculator gives you a different answer than Python gives you. Even Windows calculator does a passable job on cuberoot(33076161), whereas the answer given by python will be minutely incorrect unless you use rounding.

So, the question you ask is fundamentally unanswerable since it assumes capabilities that do not exist in floating point math.

Wrong Answer #1: This actually rounds instead of truncating, but for the cases you specified, it provides the correct output, probably due to rounding compensating for the inherent floating point precision problem you will hit in case #2:

```
print "%3.10f" % 10**(1.0/3.0)
```

Wrong Answer #2: But you could truncate (as a string) an 11-digit rounded value, which, as has been pointed out to me, would fail for values very near rollover, and in other strange ways, so DON'T do this:

```
print ("%3.11f" % 10**(1.0/3.0))[:-1]
```

Reasonably Close Answer #3: I wrote a little function that is for display only:

```
import math
def str_truncate(f,d):
    s = f*(10.0**(d))
    str = `math.trunc(s)`.rstrip('L')
    n = len(str)-d
    w = str[0:n]
    if w=='':
        w='0'
    ad =str[n:d+n]
    return w+'.'+ad



d =  8**(1.0/3.0)
t=str_truncate(d,10)
print 'case 1',t

d =  33076161**(1.0/3.0)
t=str_truncate(d,10)
print 'case 2',t

d =  10000**(1.0/3.0)
t=str_truncate(d,10)
print 'case 3',t

d = 0.1**(1.0/3.0)
t=str_truncate(d,10)
print 'case 4',t
```

Note that Python fails to perform exactly as per your expectations in case #2 due to your friendly neighborhood floating point precision being non-infinite.

You should maybe know about this document too:

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse320/Documents/FloatingPoint.pdf)

And you might be interested to know that Python has add-ons that provide [arbitary precision](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) features that will allow you to calculate the cube root of something to any number of decimals you might want. Using packages like mpmath, you can free yourself from the accuracy limitations of conventional floating point math, but at a considerable cost in performance (speed).

It is interesting to me that the built-in decimal unit does not solve this problem, since 1/3 is a rational (repeating) but non-terminating number in decimal, thus it can't be accurately represented either in decimal notation, nor floating point:

```
 import decimal
 third = decimal.Decimal(1)/decimal.Decimal(3)
 print  decimal.Decimal(33076161)**third  # cuberoot using decimal
```

output:
    320.9999999999999999999999998

Update: Sven provided this cool use of Logs which works for this particular case, it outputs the desired 321 value, instead of 320.99999...:  Nifty.  I love Log(). However this works for 321 cubed, but fails in the case of 320 cubed:

```
 exp(log(33076161)/3)
```

It seems that fractions doesn't solve this problem, but I wish it did:

```
import fractions

third = fractions.Fraction(1,3)

def cuberoot(n):
    return n ** third

print '%.14f'%cuberoot(33076161)
```

Comment: Author want truncation, not rounding as in your example

Comment: According to python docs, f truncates instead of round, but actually you are right, it rounds.

Comment: @Warren: Your second code snippet neither rounds nor truncates, but does something rather strange that sometimes conincides with truncation.

Comment: Sven: When would it fail? [:-1] simply erases the last character in the string.

Comment: @Warren: It first rounds to 11 digits.  This rounding may change any number of digits in the whole string.  Deleting the last character in the string afterwards won't undo the effects of rounding.

Comment: Oh I see.  Due to carry-concerns it could round "0.99999999999999999" to 1.0.

Comment: It would not have to be that extreme.  If the eleventh place after the comma is 9 and the twelth is 5 or above, your code will fail.

Comment: Okay, so round+truncate sucks. Thanks.

Comment: Try your new code with `10000**(1.0/3.0)`.  It will fail again.

Comment: This is harder than I thought.

Comment: oh yeah. forgot about those pesky 0.x cases.

Comment: `0.1` is still not working.  You will need something like `.rstrip("L")` to conditionally strip off the `L` indicating a long int; or use `str` instead of backticks for the conversion from int to string; or simply use the code in my answer, which would make the whole job trivial.

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 17**(1.0/3.0)
num = int(num * 100000000000)/100000000000.0
print "%.10f" % num
```

Comment: As has been pointed out above the "%.10f" above adds in rounding, which the OP does NOT want.

Comment: @Warren P: you might notice line between `num = 17**(1.0/3.0)` and `printf`, which resolves rounding issue

Answer (score 0):

What about this code .. I have created it for my personal use. although it is so simple, it is working well.

```
def truncation_machine(original,edge):
'''
Function of the function :) :
    it performs truncation operation on long decimal numbers.
Input:
    a) the number that needs to undergo truncation.
    b) the no. of decimals that we want to KEEP.
Output:
    A clean truncated number.
Example: original=1.123456789
         edge=4
         output=1.1234
'''
import math
g=original*(10**edge)
h=math.trunc(g)
T=h/(10**edge)
print('The original number ('+str(original)+') underwent a '+str(edge)+'-digit truncation to be in the form: '+str(T))
return T
```